# Read files under /src/main/resources and /web-inf/classes

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, tomcat

I have multiple css, images and text files under /src/main/resources/. I have to look what all are the files end with css and downloading them into separate folder. Similar for images (ends with jpg) and for text (ends with txt). So I have written code like this.

```
final File folder = new File("src/main/resources/");
```

and passing this to below method :

```
public void listFilesForFolder(final File folder) {
        for (final File fileEntry : folder.listFiles()) {
            if (fileEntry.isDirectory()) {
                listFilesForFolder(fileEntry);
            } else {
                System.out.println(fileEntry.getName());
                if (fileEntry.getName().endsWith(".css")) {
                    try {

                        copyFileUsingApacheCommonsIO(new File(folder.getPath() + "\\" + fileEntry.getName()),
                                new File(cssFolder + "\\" + fileEntry.getName()));
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This is working fine when I run this is spring-boot app. 
But when I am taking war and running it in apache tomcat, files are moving under /WEB-INF/classes/.

So I have changed the code like below :

```
ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
final File folder = new File(classLoader.getResource("/").getPath());
```

And it is working fine while running as war in tomcat. But above code is not working while running as spring-boot app.

How can I have a common code which will work for both running as spring boot app and also running in tom-cat?
Common code should look into /src/main/resources directory when running as spring boot app and should look into /WEB-INF/classes directory when running as war in apache tomcat?

Comment: There is no `src/main/resources`... That will be the root of the classpath that doesn't exists on the file system anymore once you package and run your application. The code should load it from the classpath. Also when packing it isn't a file anymore as it is packaged in a jar.

Comment: Maybe not the most elegant solution but it should work: use some property (or other things you can check) to see in what environment the application is running and use the appropriate code. Reading files from a source directory wouldn't be recommended though as in production you'd not want to have it and your dev environment should be as close to production as possible in order to spot bugs faster.

Comment: Actually `this.getClass().getResource("/").getPath` gets access to `/target/test-classes`. In that folder, during runtime, all the content of your `src/main/resources` should be copied.

Can you check, at runtime, what you have in the `target` folder? (Just put a breakpoint somewhere in those lines and run your code in debug mode, then, when it stops, check the content of the target folder of your project)